# All floats are doubles?

Tags: c++

I'm reading textbook that says this:

> C++ treats all floating-point numbers you type in a program's source code (such as 7.33 and 0.0975) as double values by default.

I find this a bit odd and have never heard of it. Seems wasteful? Why get extra precision if you don't specify it? Why have two different types that mean the same thing? What about a long double?

Comment: @doctorlove: http://books.google.com/books?id=OANiO7ZXPHEC&pg=PA71&lpg=PA71&dq=%22treats+all+floating-point+numbers+you+type%22&source=bl&ots=BY-lyRUcON&sig=tMaDRGz5MUkACt-zCeiixBJKr3w&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6lLJUfLlKISE9gSS3YCQAg&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22treats%20all%20floating-point%20numbers%20you%20type%22&f=false.

Comment: `double d = 7.33; float f = 7.33f;`

Comment: The quote is very misleading. `12.3f` is a floating point number you can type in a program's source code, and it is `float`.

Comment: +1 because it is not your fault, it is a misleading text on that book.

Comment: flout and double have different boundries and precision. Actually I have never reached limits of flout in real project, but in some cases precision is needed so these two things mean different. And that sentence from book sounds like author is philosopher or something else, but not programmer.

Comment: @juanchopanza Well, it's a floating point literal of type `float`, the actual number would be `12.3`. ;)

Comment: The text in the book is only misleading if you start out thinking that "float" means exactly the same as "floating point number".

Comment: @Spook Indeed I've been using SO awhile and understand how it works :) I will accept an answer once I've had time to review them all in detail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is referring to [floating-point literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal) only.

This is the same as saying that any integer number you write in code is always treated as a (signed) `int`. As soon as you assign this to a variable, you will get the type of the variable.

However, when using standalone literals in computation you will get the type of the literal for that computation, potentially triggering implicit type conversions:

```
float f = 3.141;    // f is of type float, even though the literal was double
auto d = f * 2.0;   // d will be of type double because of the literal 2.0
auto f2 = f * 2.0f; // f2 will be of type float again
```

The computation on the second line involves two different types: The *type of the variable* `f` is `float`. Even though it was constructed from a `double` literal, the type of the variable is what counts. The *type of the literal* `2.0` on the other hand is `double` and hence triggers an implicit conversion for the computation. The actual multiplication is therefore performed as a multiplication of two `double`s.

If you want a standalone value to have a specific type, use the matching literal.

Comment: Or you can make the int unsigned with the 'u' suffix - if I'm not wrong, long time no C++.

Comment: Exactly. There's [quite](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal) [a number](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal) [of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) [suffixes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) for the different literals. In C++11 you can even [define your own](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal).

Answer (score 21):

This is a part of language specification. If you want a double, write:

```
auto a = 12.3;
```

If you want a float, write:

```
auto a = 12.3f;
```

If you want a long double, write:

```
auto a = 12.3L;
```

Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfh6f0w2.aspx)

The whole topic is extensively described in C++ standard in chapter `2.14 Literals`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Lets change it to `auto a = ` then

Comment: @Spook Hey, I added a comparison with integral types for illustration :) I thought it would be better than copying your answer and adding it there. Feel free to remove it altogether or edit it heavily, though! (Also, I wasn't warned about your previous edit. Didn't SO use to warn about overwriting other people's edits?)

Comment: @MagnusHoff: I don't think your edit was correct; `char` operands are promoted to `int` when being divided, so your two snippets would give the same result.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I'm not good at quoting the standard, but both g++ 4.2.1 and clang++ 4.0 give the results I posted (150 and 22)

Comment: @MagnusHoff It indeed should. I reverted, because you removed some crucial informations in the process of editing (about long double and MSDN source). OP asked only about floating point types and that's why I didn't included the integral ones. You are always able to post comments, I can modify my post afterwards, basing on your suggestions :)

Comment: @MagnusHoff: Ah, my mistake; I didn't notice that 300 was out of range!

Comment: @Spook In this case I thought it clearer to add my suggestion as an edit, because of formatting and such. You are of course still the arbiter of what finally goes into your answer ;)

Answer (score 4):

I actually think the text in the book is correct. I'm paraphrasing a little bit:

> By default a floating point valud, such as `12.3` is a `double`.

In other words, if you don't add the letter "f" at the end of the number, to make it `12.3f`, it is indeed a double.

Most of the time (if floating point calculations are just a small part of the code), this makes little difference, but if you have floating point variables, and use `double` constants for initialization and comparison, there will be an extra conversion from `float` to `double`. And of course, the storage needed for the constants will be larger, for example.

Comment: Is it even ALLOWED to optimize a `double` to `float` comparison, for example, into `float`? Maybe when it's a constant?

Comment: As every `float` value can be represented exactly with `double` (at least with IEEE-754), then I would expect that the compiler could optimize e.g. `float x = ...; if (x == 3.14)` to `if (x == 3.14f)`.  There may be some edge-case I'm not considering, though.