# Why does auto deduce this variable as double and not float?

Tags: c++, floating-point, literals, auto, type-deduction

In the snippet below, `auto` deduces the variable to `double`, but I want `float`.

```
auto one = 3.5;
```

Does it always use `double` for literals with a decimal point?  How does it decide between float and double?

Comment: To answer your **exact** question (instead of what you wanted to know) -- `auto` deduces it that way because templates deduce it that way.  Templates deduce it that way because function overloading does (function overloading rules are used to break ties).

Comment: You mean to say that it's an overload resolution of `type` here?

Comment: I mean to say that the rule that makes `auto one = 3.5;` deduce `double` is the same rule that make `int f(float); int f(double);` choose `f(double)` when presented with `f(3.5)`.  Your question has nothing peculiar to `auto`, it only involves the type and category of the floating-point literal `3.5`

Comment: Because `3.5` is a `double`, not a `float`.

Comment: As a note, arithmetic types default to `int` for integer literals, `double` for floating-point literals, `char` for character literals, and `bool` for boolean literals.

Comment: @JustinTime: Although in C, character literals are type `int`, which can cause subtle errors when code that looks like C is compiled with both C and C++ compilers, but depends on character literals being specifically `char` or `int` (and even more fun, potentially depends on the implementation defined signedness of `char`).

Comment: there are so many dupllicates: [All floats are doubles?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17292371/995714), [How a floating point literal is treated either double or float in Visual C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8757815/995714), [why sizeof(13.33) is 8 bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5537276/995714), [What is the type of the value 1.0e+1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30260830/995714), [How function overloading works with double and float](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54090448/995714)...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Type of literal `3.5` is `double`. For `float` please use `3.5f`

You can play with [this snippet](http://www.ideone.com/fT1Jkl) to see various type information.

Answer (score 7):

`3.5` is a `double` literal. Thus `auto` correctly deduces its type as `double`. You can still use it to initialize a `float` variable, but the most correct way is to use a `float` literal like `3.5f`. The `f` at the end is called a suffix. Suffixes for floating point literals are:

- (no suffix) defines double
- `f` `F` defines float
- `l` `L` defines long double

Besides [floating point literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal), there are also suffixes for [integral literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) and [user-defined literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal).

Answer (score 7):

In C++ (and C), floating literals are treated as `double` by default unless specified by `f or F or l or L`.

The standard has following:

> 2.14.4
>   The type of a floating literal is double unless explicitly specified by a suffix. The suffixes f and F specify
>   float, the suffixes l and L specify long double. If the scaled value is not in the range of representable values for its type, the program is ill-formed.

Hence,

```
auto one = 3.5;
```

is always `double` and if you intend `float`
it should be coded as

```
auto one = 3.5f;
```

Answer (score 1):

The type of a floating point literal in C++ is automatically `double` unless:

1. `f` is suffixed, in which case the type of the literal is `float`
2. `L` is suffixed, in which case the type of the literal is `long double`

So, if you want your variable to be a `float`, do this:

```
auto one = 3.5f;
```